# Dentro de un if quiero crear una condición cuando un botón tiene una imagen especifica

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un botón que cambia de imagen de fondo cada vez que se le hace click a otras imágenes. Entonces, cuando por ejemplo este botón llamado `miniatura` tiene la `imagen1`, quiero que haga algo. Pero si tiene la `imagen2`, haga otra cosa. Y así hasta tener la `imagenN`. Pero creo que tener un `if` con esa información dentro no es una opción. No encuentro cuál sea. La idea principal es que cuando `imagen1` aparezca y se presione, mande a otro *layout*. Que si es `imagen2`, mande a un tercer *layout*, y así para todas (son en total 9)

```
miniatura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(Drawable this.miniatura1= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que en vez de comprobar qué imagen está mostrando, guardes en otra variable un valor que te diferencia cada caso. A esta variable le das valor cada vez que cambies la imagen, con un valor único para cada diferente posibilidad. Dentro del `listener` del botón, con un `if` compruebas el valor de esa variable y en función de su valor, haces lo que tengas que hacer.

Comment: Una opción es crearte un CustomButton al cuál le pasas un hashmap con la id de la imagen como Key y el ClassName de la Activity a dónde navegar como Value.  Cuando se haga click en el botón, entonces llamas a tu custom view para que te devuelva el ClassName y ya puedes navegar. De esta manera puedes quitar el Switch-Case de la Activity.  En función del caso puedes tener un hashmap en una clase aparte con varios key-values y a la custom sólo le pasas la id de la imagen.  Cuando lo necesites, la custom accederá a ese map.

Comment: Las vistas en android tienen una propiedad llamada TAG donde podrias guardar un valor de estado distinto cada vez que cambias de imagen y luego haces un swich case con ese valor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Es facil , en lugar de controlar la accion que se ejecuta dependiendo de la imagen mostrada, lo que debes controlar es un valor numerico,  que dependiendo de este valor , se mostrara la imagen y la accion asociados a ese valor... por ejemplo imaginate que tienes tres imagenes llamadas

imagen1.jpg
imagen2.jpg
imagen3.jpg

pues bien , lo primero que puedes hacer es  meter el nombre de las imagenes en un array de tipo String

```
  String[] imagenes = {"imagen1.jpg", "imagen2.jpg", "imagen3.jpg"};
```

luego te creas una variable numerica, donde guardaremos guardaremos el numero de indice de la posicion que ocupa en el array, la imagen que quieras mostrar por ejemplo, si queremos mostrar "imagen2.jpg" debera guardar un 1, ya que es el indice de la posicion que ocupa en el array

```
Int indexImagenSeleccionada=1
```

una vez hecho esto , recuperamos el nombre de la imagen que ocupa la posicion del array , con indice igual al numero guardado en la variable

```
String nombreImageSeleccionada=imagenes[indexImagenSeleccionada]
```

y ahora mostramos la imagen

MyImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(nombreImageSeleccionada, "drawable", getPackageName())

ahora solo queda en  el evento onclick del boton, meter un switch donde, dependiendo el indice guardado en la variable **indexImagenSeleccionada**, se hara la accion correspondiente

por ejemplo

```
switch(indexImagenSeleccionada) {
  case 0:
  codigo que se ejecuta imagen1.jpg
    break;
  case 1:
    codigo que se ejecuta imagen2.jpg
    break;

}
```